# htaccess to remove file extension and change folder

Tags: file, .htaccess, directory

When people access mysite, for example `mysite.com/folder1/i-love-stackoverflow`, i'd like the file `/home/myaccount/public_html/mysite.com/folder1/folder2/i-love-stackoverflow.html` to be shown

My current `.htaccess` file in `/home/myaccount/public_html/mysite.com/folder1/.htaccess` is like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.html [L]
```

But this htaccess file can only remove the html extension. It works only when the file `i-love-stackoverflow.html` is in `folder1`

Could anyone help me with this? I'm not very familiar with htaccess.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I register new host and there is no folder2 now. .htaccess file in `/home/myaccount/public_html/`. Html files in `/home/myaccount/public_html/folder1` The following codes works well for me

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder1/$1\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder1/$1\.html [L]
```